# Mac OSX command hg branch name autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, terminal, mercurial, branch

We have used the mercurial for our project. I am using hg via terminal for add, commit & push the changes.

While moving one branch to another branch i need autocomplete of branch names.

hg update reg`<tab>`

It should display the branch name and auto complete that name.

`hg update registration`

Please suggest is any way to achieve this approach.

Advance thanks !!

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/tab-completion-for-mercurial-in-bash - should be relevant to OSX too.

Answer (score 3):

If you have setup mercurial with brew and your version is recent you probably have a hg-completion.bash file in your install already.(Otherwise you can download a version [here](http://selenic.com/hg/raw-file/25e4d2f35965/contrib/bash_completion). (I suggest you rename it hg-completion.bash))

Edit your **~/.profile** and **~/.bash_profile** files and add the following lines :

```
if [ -f /PATH_TO_YOUR_COMPLETION_FILE/hg-completion.bash ]; then
    . /PATH_TO_YOUR_COMPLETION_FILE/hg-completion.bash
fi
```

Open a new terminal tab and the autocompletion should work.

Comment: Does this complete branch names?

Comment: @GeorgeMarian Yes, it does.